# filter option not showing for dynamic dataTable in asp.net core razor pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, datatables

I have a page, which displays customer names with attendance details. I have displayed the attendance details inside a modal-pop up. The data are displayed inside a modal pop up using jquery datatables with filtering options(search,pagination..).

The issues i am facing here is the filtering options are only for the first customers when it comes for the second customer,it is not showing. I tried to pass the customer id for the datatable. But it is not showing the filtering option for second/third customer.

Please find my code and screenshot below. Appreciate your help on this.

```
<!---Customer Div Starts Here---->
@for (int i = 0; i < groups.Count(); i += 4)
{
    <div class="row mt-2">
        @{
            int j = 0;
            for (; j <= 3 && i + j < groups.Count(); j++)
            {
                //if(Model.GetCusAttOverview[i+j].AttendancePercentage != 0){
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card border-0" style="height:440px;">
                        <div class="card-header" style="background-image: linear-gradient(#f1b52c, #ce6d28)">
                            <a class="text-decoration-none" target="_blank" asp-page="/AttReport" asp-route-customerId="@Model.GetCusAttOverview[i+j].CustomerID"><h4 class="text-center text-white"> @groups[i+j].ToUpper()</h4></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body pb-0" style="background: rgba(57,57,57)">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    @{                                        
                                        int n = @Model.GetCusAttOverview[i + j].AttendancePercentage;
                                        var BarColor = @Model.OnGetBarColor(n);
                                        BarColor.ToString();
                                    }
                                    <div class="overallchart" data-percent="@Model.GetCusAttOverview[i+j].AttendancePercentage" data-barcolor="@BarColor.Content">@Model.GetCusAttOverview[i+j].AttendancePercentage%</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer" style="background: rgb(57,57,57); ">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <h6 class="text-center text-white  p-3">TOTAL EMPLOYEES</h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    @{
                                        string CustName = groups[i+j].Replace(",", "").Replace("&", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("'", "").Replace(" ", "");
                                    }
                                    <h6 class="text-center text-white p-3"> ATTENDANCE <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalCustAttendance_@CustName"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info fa-2" style="color: #009add;"></i></a></h6>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6" style="background-image:linear-gradient(to right,#009add,#005486)">
                                    <h3 class="text-center text-white">@Model.GetCusAttOverview[i+j].TotalEmployees</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6" style="background-image:linear-gradient(to right,#82bc00,#006432)">
                                    <h3 class="text-center text-white">@Model.GetCusAttOverview[i+j].Attendance</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal" id="modalCustAttendance_@CustName" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header text-center">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Attendance Details - @Model.GetCusAttOverview[i + j].CustomerName</h4>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="row mb-2">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                                <input asp-for="@Model.CustomerId" type="hidden" value='@Model.GetCusAttOverview[i + j].CustomerID' id="hdnCustomerId"/>
                                                <button asp-page-handler="Download" class="btn float-end" style="background-color:#009add">Download Report</button>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                                <table class="table table-hover" id="data" style="width:100%">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th>
                                                                Employee Number
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th>
                                                                Employee Name
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th>
                                                                Function
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th>
                                                                Shift
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th>
                                                                Attendance
                                                            </th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        @foreach (var item in Model.GetCusOverviewAttendance.Where(c => c.CustomerID == Model.GetCusAttOverview[i + j].CustomerID))
                                                        {
                                                            string FontColor = "";
                                                            @if (item.Attendance == "Absent")
                                                            {
                                                                FontColor = "Red";
                                                            }
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style='color: @(FontColor);'>
                                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeNumber)
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td style='color: @(FontColor);'>
                                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeName)
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td style='color: @(FontColor);'>
                                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FunctionName)
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td style='color: @(FontColor);'>
                                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShiftName)
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td style='color: @(FontColor);'>
                                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Attendance)
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        }
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                //}
            }
        }
    </div>
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        
        $('#data').DataTable()({
            
            'searching': true
            
        })
        
    });
</script>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because all of the table own the same id(`data` in your case), you need give a unique id for each table.

For your current code, you may change your table id like below:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="data_@i" style="width:100%">
```

Then change your js code like below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {    
        $('[id^="data"]').DataTable({    
            'searching': true   
        })

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for our help. It worked as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this line correct?

```
   $('#data').DataTable()({
        
        'searching': true
        
    })
```

It Should be.

```
    $('#data').DataTable({
        'searching': true
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Even after i changed it , i am not able to show the search and pagination options for other customer details.

Comment: @Teena Any issue you are getting in console?

Comment: @Teena we can look into it if you still struggling with it.